# Modulate Time in Logic Pro X?

Tags: audio, music, logic

Before I started using Logic Pro, I was using Fruity Loops, and in that program you can very easily modulate time (I hope that is the correct term for this).  By this I mean it acts like the sound is on a record and you can push and pull the record while it spins.  This sound is like what you hear in most dubstep songs.  A very easy way to do this in Fruity Loops was using the Gross Beat plugin.

I have looked up how to do this, but all I can find is the Flex Time option for sound files, this only speeds up and slows down the clip linearly.  I would like to be able to do an ease automation, and I am using MIDI, not actual sound.

In Logic Pro I have found a few things that produce a similar sound.

- **Glide** I can make the MIDI instrument have a glide, and I can make it glide from the note that was played before to the one I want it to play.  But this is very inconvenient because it makes me have to create a note that I do not want before the note I want the effect done to (which will create unwanted sounds that can break the flow of the song.
- **Cutoff** Changing the cutoff value through automations can create a similar noise, but this does not effect the time at all, and will create more work than I would like.
- **BPM** I can automate the BPM, but this does the opposite of changing the cutoff value, it only slows it down and doesn't create any sounds.  It does, due to me using the Tape Delay, create an annoying high pitched click because of the dramatic speed up after the automation.  Changing the BPM also, obviously, messes up the BPM of the song, by this I mean it makes the song slower in that part but doesn't make it faster when its done to catch back up to where it is supposed to be.  This also effects the entire song, and not one specific instrument.

What I want, specifically, is a way to change the speed and pitch of the instrument for a short time, through automation, and when it is set back to normal it will speed the audio back up (or slows it down) so that the instrument catches up to where it should be.

Is there a built in way to do this in Logic Pro X? If there isn't, is there a plugin I can get to accomplish this?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the fade tool for this and use the automation curve tool to adjust to your requirements.
By default the fade tool is set for volume fade in/fade out, but you can change this to speed to get the same effect. It's not like a DJ spin back, but a stop/start.
Hope that helps.